# Least number not being the determinant of a set of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let n > 1 be a natural number and u < v integers. How can I determine the least
 natural number not being the determinant of some n x n - matrix with integers in the
 range u..v without calculating simply all the determinants ?

I know that there are upper bounds for the determinant with given size and range
 of the entries, but how can all the possible values be determined efficiently ?